# Multiple join query in a scope/named_scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, scope, named-scope

Is it possible to create a named_scope from the following query:

```
SELECT g.*, b.*
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN band_users bu ON u.id = bu.uid 
LEFT JOIN bands b ON bu.bid = b.id 
LEFT JOIN bands_gigs bg ON b.id = bg.bid 
LEFT JOIN gigs g ON bg.gid = g.id
WHERE u.id = 1
```

I am struggling to do it, is it possible to represent multiple :joins in a named_scope or rails 3 scope?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done with:

```
class Band < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :gigs

  ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bands

  scope :my_scope, joins(:bands => :gigs)
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks mosch, so a controller would look like @gigs = User.find(1).my_scope ?